# Coroutineで大量の処理を並列実行したい

Tags: kotlin

KotlinのCoroutineで大量の処理を複数実行したいです。処理を並列実行するには以下のように、asyncで動かして、awaitで待ち合せればいいとのことですが、この処理が大量にある場合はどうしたらいいのでしょうか？

例えば以下のprocess関数に1～1000を代入して関数を走らせるとします。それぞれの処理に1秒かかるとしたら、普通にやれば1000秒、並列処理で行えば1秒で処理が終わることになります。しかし、以下のように1000個すべてにawait()と書くわけにもいきませんし、そもそも1000という数が動的に変わる値であったら対応できません。

このような場合はどのように並列処理を実現するのでしょうか？

```
fun runMain(): Job = scope.launch {
    val price1 = async { process(1) }
    val price2 = async { process(2) }
    println("Result: ${price1.await()}, ${price2.await()}")
}
```

※マルチポスト
少し急いでいますので、マルチポストさせていただきます。[Taratail](https://teratail.com/questions/271128)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

解決しました。
以下のようにループでコルーチンを作成し、awaitで待ち合わせればいいそうです。
ありがとうございました。

```
// count個のasyncを起動して待ち合わせ
val prices = (1..count)
    .map { async { process(it) } }
    .map { it.await() }
println("Results: ${prices})
```